# View [welcome] not found

Tags: php, laravel, google-app-engine, gcloud

I deployed my Laravel app (with Cloud SQL integration) onto Google App Engine with the following settings.

## app.yaml

```
runtime: php73

env_variables:
  LOG_CHANNEL: stackdriver
  APP_LOG: errorlog
  APP_KEY: [APP KEY]
  APP_URL: "http://example.com/"
  APP_STORAGE: /tmp
  VIEW_COMPILED_PATH: /tmp
  CACHE_DRIVER: database
  SESSION_DRIVER: database
  DB_DATABASE: cbt-sql
  DB_USERNAME: root
  DB_PASSWORD: [PASSWORD]
  DB_SOCKET: "[SOCKET DETAILS]"
```

I ran the usual config/cache/view/route clear commands.

Using `gcloud beta app deploy --no-cache`, I got the following error:

```
View [welcome] not found.
```

However, looking at my codes directory, the view is clearly there.

[image: GAE Stackdriver Debugger]

What did I do wrong?

```
(1/1) InvalidArgumentException
View [welcome] not found.

in FileViewFinder.php line 137
at FileViewFinder->findInPaths('welcome', array('/workspace/resources/views'))
in FileViewFinder.php line 79
at FileViewFinder->find('welcome')
in Factory.php line 131
at Factory->make('welcome', array(), array())
in helpers.php line 975
at view('welcome')
in WelcomeController.php line 14
at WelcomeController->index()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(WelcomeController), 'index'), array())
in Controller.php line 54
at Controller->callAction('index', array())
in ControllerDispatcher.php line 45
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(WelcomeController), 'index')
in Route.php line 219
at Route->runController()
in Route.php line 176
at Route->run()
in Router.php line 680
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php line 130
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in SubstituteBindings.php line 41
at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php line 171
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 76
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php line 171
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php line 171
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in StartSession.php line 56
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php line 171
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php line 171
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in EncryptCookies.php line 66
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php line 171
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php line 105
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure))
in Router.php line 682
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request))
in Router.php line 657
at Router->runRoute(object(Request), object(Route))
in Router.php line 623
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request))
in Router.php line 612
at Router->dispatch(object(Request))
in Kernel.php line 176
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php line 130
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in TransformsRequest.php line 21
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php line 171
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in TransformsRequest.php line 21
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php line 171
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in ValidatePostSize.php line 27
at ValidatePostSize->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php line 171
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 62
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php line 171
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in TrustProxies.php line 57
at TrustProxies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php line 171
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php line 105
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure))
in Kernel.php line 151
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request))
in Kernel.php line 116
at Kernel->handle(object(Request))
in index.php line 59


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/byOzf.png
```

Comment: did you followed [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-standard)? Especially step #3?

Comment: Yes I did. Every single step.

Comment: I think what @gooooo means is that you need to add layouts to your file directory (views > layouts > welcome.blade.php). It would look something like this: `FileViewFinder->findInPaths('welcome', array('/workspace/resources/views/layouts'))` Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @revvy - Did you manage to solve this issue, I exactly everything that you have mentioned as well and now m stuck with this exact same error?

Answer (score 1):

> FileViewFinder->findInPaths('welcome', array('/workspace/resources/views'))

Check your path

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I meant view `welcome` is not found, at path `/workspace/resources/views`. So please check in that folder contains welcome source file or not